# Jekyll Nested Data

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a nested yaml data file for my jekyll blog like so:

```yaml
Nickname1:
      name: John
      address: Johnstreet 1

Nickname2:
     name: Rudolf
     address: Rudolfstreet 1
```

I use this to print additional information after each post, which I specify in the front matter. This works fine.

I now wish to create a site that lists all entries of this data file. This should in theory be easy:

```
{% for nickname in site.data.NAMEOFFILE %}
    <li> {{ nickname.address }} </li>
{% endfor %}
```

However, this does not work because the YAML data is nested. The data has to remain nested, and each entry needs to have a different nickname. The problem with that is of course that I am unable to loop over all entries, because they are all differently named.

Can you folks help me out here? Is there any way in which I can achieve this without changing the nested structure of my data file? Changing the nested structure would break large parts of my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jekyll data files can be set up in two formats: list or dictionary (not the official terminology, but that's what I call them and what helps me understand them).

Lists are used for iteration. Dictionaries are used for looking up an individual item and shouldn't be used in iteration.

```
// list.yml
- nickname: Nickname1
  name: John
  address: Johnstreet 1

- nickname: Nickname2
  name: Rudolf
  address: Rudolfstreet 1

...

// usage
{% for person in site.data.list %}
    <li> {{ person.address }} </li>
{% endfor %}
```

```
// dictionary.yml
Nickname1:
  name: John
  address: Johnstreet 1

Nickname2:
  name: Rudolf
  address: Rudolfstreet 1

...

// usage
{% assign person = site.data.dictionary['Nickname1'] %}
<ul>
    <li> {{ person.address }} </li>
</ul>
```

I have the same data in two different files: one in a list format and one in a dictionary format. That lets me iterate or do specific lookups whenever I need. Drawbacks are that you have duplicated data across two different files and need to maintain consistency whenever you make changes.

To solve your specific problem, I would make another data file with the data formatted into a list so that you can iterate through the data. This means you don't need to change the file with the nested structure and can avoid breaking the site.

[Jekyll docs example on 'dictionary' usage](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/#example-accessing-a-specific-author)

[Jekyll docs example on 'list' usage](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/#example-list-of-members)

Comment: I was hoping to avoid redundancies by introducing a second data file with essentially the same data, just differently structured.  But it seems as this might be the only plausible solution.

Comment: I agree, redundant files are not optimal. But, the flexibility in iterating or doing lookups is nice. I'm sure there's a fancy/complicated way of using lots of liquid tags to do iteration and lookups based off one file, but I think the redundancy is worth the tradeoff for simpler code.

Answer (score 2):

When you iterate over an object, the iteration variable is a two-element array with the key at index 0 and the value at index 1:

```html
<ul>
  {% for nickname in site.data.people -%}
    <li>
      {{ nickname[0] }}: name {{ nickname[1].name }},
      address {{ nickname[1].address }}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

renders (after whitespace cleanup) as

```html
<ul>
  <li>Nickname1: name John, address Johnstreet 1</li>
  <li>Nickname2: name Rudolf, address Rudolfstreet 1</li>
</ul>
```

Weirdly, I can't find this described anywhere in the Liquid docs, neither on the [Jekyll site](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/) nor in the [official documentation](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/iteration/). The only reference I've seen is on the [platformOS documentation page](https://documentation.platformos.com/api-reference/liquid/loops#iterating-over-a-hash).